# Is the turns ratio still equal to voltage ratio in a non-ideal transformer?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, electrical-engineering

For a non-ideal transformer, is the following equation still true?
$$
\frac{V_S}{V_P} = \frac{N_S}{N_P}
$$

All the books I have consulted (mainly first-year undergraduate physics textbooks) merely proved the above equation using Faraday's law of electromagnetic induction for the case where the transformer is ideal. Yes, some of them did mention that, for non-ideal transformer,
$$
\frac{N_S}{N_P}\neq\frac{I_P}{I_S}
$$
but none explicitly discuss if
$$
\frac{V_S}{V_P} \neq \frac{N_S}{N_P}
$$

If possible, please do not explain with too profound physics concepts because I am not that great at this topic. Thank you.

Comment: There are about half a dozen different effects in the non-ideal transformer, starting with the loss of flux, non-linearity of the core, capacitance of the windings, resistance of the windings etc.. Physicists don't care about those much. If you want a thorough treatment, then you will have to look at a EE analysis of real devices. Which of these effects is of importance depends on the type of the transformer and the application. For low frequency transformers it's mostly winding resistance and loss of flux. Some of the magnetic field of the primary does not go through the secondary coil.

Comment: If you google "Colonel McLyman Transformer Handbook" you should find an excellent reference on the engineering issues with designing and using transformers.

Comment: @FlatterMann So am I right to say that, in general, the equality between turns ratio and voltage ratio is no longer guaranteed for non-ideal transformer?

Comment: @ThePhoton Wow, this book is so comprehensive. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: No. One can have lower and higher voltages. A good example of a transformer that generates a higher voltage is a resonant Tesla coil.